# php multilanguage filename upload

Tags: php, html, utf-8, filenames, multilingual

im trying to allow users to upload theyr pictures to the website and show them by theyr original file names. in english everything goes as planned, but when i try to upload a file who is in a different language with spaces it uploads the file as: ".jpg" only without a filename just the filetype. or some ugly text that cant be read as a link (src="") from the website.
at first i used windows(xampp) but then i understood the utf-8 problem and i bought a linux server, things got alittle better but still not a 100% success.

(btw i know theres an option for database filename storage and real filename as a unique number, but im not sure its the best solution for me since it will slow down the server reading tons of files from database.)

can somone point me to my mistake?

index.html:

```
<script>
    $('#transFrame').load(function () {
    alert("file uploaded");
    ...fix the file into the img src="..";
    });
</script>
    <form target="transFrame" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"      value="200000" /> Choose image to upload:  
    <input  id = "imagefile" name="uploadedfile" type="file" onchange="submit();" /><br />
                </form>
<iframe style="display:none;" name="transFrame" id="transFrame"></iframe>
```

---

upload.php:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "success" . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] ;
    } else{
        echo "failed" . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] ;
    }
```

Comment: best you do rename all uploaded files by date or so :-) witch different language prefix( en_, fr_, de_).

Comment: but i want the users to be able to upload files and keep theyr original filenames.

Comment: the problem is: you server maybe not support client language. You can try to add to your form file field accept-charset="UTF-8" and in php utf8_encode($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).